# Center these single posts on my Tumblr

Tags: jquery, html, css, tumblr

Im botching together a tumblr theme really quickly, i need to get the content on single posts to center. I think Masonry is forcing it to be absolutely positioned top:0 and left:0

here's an example: http://emilestest.tumblr.com/post/31114466201

Any ideas

Comment: You want to center the image or the post and the image together?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand what you want to do. Is you want to center the container you should add text-align center to the body and fix width and add margin auto to the container:

```
body {
  background-color:#EFE9E1;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
#container {
  background-color:#EFE9E1;
  min-width:1024px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  width:1024px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```